# Superconductivity and superfluidity in bosonic and fermionic condensates

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

Can bosonic and fermionic condensates explain superfluid and superconducting properties? Are they better than the theory of BCS and Landau?

Edited:

My question is based in this lecture pesentation [From BEC to CBS](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.physi.uni-heidelberg.de/~fschney/2008SS-Preseminar/BEC_BCS.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjUm4WM9PXWAhXHipAKHVDyDcAQFggoMAA&usg=AOvVaw2F4LmxANOVY9bWxpFIvV6v). In particular in this slide:
[image]

Comment: "Bosonic and fermionic condensates" is not a theory. Until you actually have a theory, your question isn't really answerable. What's more, BCS theory already involves fermionic condensates.

Comment: @Chris please, check out my edit.

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  What two things are you trying to compare?  BCS and Landaus theory of super-fluidity are how you describe weak coupling condensates.  " bosonic and fermionic condensates" are things with superfluid or superconducting properties (zero viscosity, quantized vortices...) not theories themselves.

Comment: Did you at least check on Wikipedia the following keywords : Bose-Einstein condensate, Fermi-Dirac degenerate gas, Landau theory of the Fermi liquid, BCS theory of superconductivity, superfluidity ? Your question make no sense at all once you read understand these concepts. If you have difficulties understanding one of these concepts, please ask specific question.

Comment: Superfluidity in He^4 is more or less a Bose-Einstein condensate, in He^3 it comes from Cooper pairing of fermions to form a quasi Bose-Einstein condensate. The second order phase transition is responsible for the phenomenology of the superfluid state. A superconductor is a pseudo Bose-Einstein condensate made on top of the Cooper instability in the Fermi gas (also called a metal, this later being described by the Landau theory of the Fermi liquid). The superconducting phenomenology is explained by a Anderson-Higgs phenomenon (the electromagnetic gauge redundancy goes to a smaller group).

Comment: The Anderson-Higgs phenomenon is encapsulated in the Bardeen-Cooper-Schriffer (BCS) model, as it is in the Ginzburg-Landau formalism. BCS theory is considered as the sufficient model to describe first generation superconductors (before the 80's, say). It's based on a mean-field approximation of an effective theory of the electron-phonon coupling in a Fermi liquid. Ginzburg-Landau functional describes all the electromagnetic properties of a superconductor.